# Abrir nova janela a partir de botão

Tags: java, javafx

Eu quero criar uma nova janela quando o usuário clicar em um determinado botão, enquanto essa nova janela estiver aberta, a janela principal não pode ser usada. Como posso fazer isso em JAVAFX?

Pensei em fazer a seguinte sequência de comandos na função OnAction do botão:

```
Stage s1 = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        s1.setScene(scene);
        s1.show();
```

Porém isso deixa o Stage principal (que está no método start na classe main) ainda operante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao criar o seu novo stage, você precisa colocar o outro stage como seu criador e após isso transformar a janela em "modal".

```
newStage.initOwner(parentStage);
newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```